# Crear botón con funcionalidad y que esté pueda ser invocado en otras pantallas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Que tal, me surgió una duda, quiero desarrollar un botón para guardar pero ese mismo botón quiero invocarlo en otras pantallas, ya que la función sería la misma en todas las pantallas, cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo para que en cada pantalla no este programando el mismo botón? La aplicación que estoy desarrollando esta en WPF y estoy utilizando el patrón MVVM.

Agradezco su ayuda, 
Saludos.

Comment: Sólo tengo una duda, este botón tiene un método que guarda, correcto? Pero en todas las ventas que lo quieres tener guardaría el mismo objeto? De ser así puedes hacer uso de los user Control, que es una ventana que puede ir incrustada en otras ventanas con la misma logica, en ese user control iría tu botón y lo llamarias en las ventas que requieras, si es asi me comentas para que te explique :p

Comment: @Katz no en todas las pantallas se va a guardar el mismo objeto, realmente las funcionalidades serían Guardar, Editar y regresar al Home.

Comment: Es habitual en MVVM que tengamos una clase base con acciones comunes, por lo que se me ocurre que puedes tener un ICommand en ViewModelBase que te sirva de base para el resto de la aplicación. Si quieres que los ViewModels que hereden de éste tengan que implementar los métodos de acción del ICommand obligatoriamente, puedes declarar la clase como abstracta y dejar los métodos como abstractos para que se implementen. Puedes también hacer uso de una interface y que los ViewModels que vayan a hacer uso del botón implementes la interfaz.

Answer (score 1):

Veo 2 opciones posibles:

## 1

Encapsular la logica de negocios en una clase y consumir el servicio siempre que lo necesites:

```
public class Zapatera
{
  public void GuardarZapato(Zapato zapato)
  {
    // logica para guardar el zapato aquí.
  }
}
```

Y en el evento click:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
   Zapatera zapatera = new Zapatera();
    zapatera.GuardarZapato(new Zapato{Nombre = "Eisenstodt" });
}
```

Por lo que siempre que necesites guardar un zapato, solo tendrias(literalmente) que copiar y pegar el código dentro del método.

## 2

[Crear tu propio control.](http://www.w3ii.com/es/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.html)

La idea es que defines en algún lugar una vista y que puedas reutilizar esta vista siempre que la necesites, en tu caso, un botón.

Personalmente yo que tu me fuera por la primera opcion si lo unico que necesitas es guardar o mostrar algo y no necesitas de hilo de la vista. De lo contrario crearía mi propio control.

Comment: Encapsular la lógica y llamar al método cuando lo requería es para mi la mejor opción, me la he complicado mucho pensando que también el no querida definir nuevamente el botón en el xaml con sus estilos y propiedades xd por eso me fui mas por un userControl

Comment: Me alegra saber eso. Si te sirvio la respuesta, pues dejanos saber.

Comment: Eso no es MVVM, no se que implementación de MVVM usan pero no se deben llamar métodos del ViewModel desde la vista. Y lo peor es llamar a lógica de negocios desde la vista.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un ViewModel "general", no asociado a ninguna vista específica y crear su instancia en el etiquetado XAML del App.xaml, de modo que así quedará disponible en toda la aplicación.

Este es el viewmodel:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class GlobalActionsViewModel
    {
        private ICommand _myCommand;
        public ICommand MyCommand
        {
            get { return _myCommand; }
            set { _myCommand = value; }
        }

        public GlobalActionsViewModel()
        {
            //MyCommand = ...
        }
    }
}
```

Esta la instancia en el App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="GlobalButton.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModels"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <vm:GlobalActionsViewModel x:Key="MyGlobalVM"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Y este el botón que puedes poner donde quieras:

```
<Button DataContext="{StaticResource MyGlobalVM}" Command="MyCommand" Content="DoIt" />
```

Y eso es, MVVM simplifica todo.

Ah! Si necesitas que el botón maneje información de algún objeto o un control lo envías al ICommand través del CommandParámeter.

Algo asi:

```
<Window x:Class="GlobalButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid"/>
        <!-- Enviar el DataGrid completo -->
        <Button DataContext="{StaticResource MyGlobalVM}" Command="MyCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrid}" Content="DoIt" />
        <!-- Enviar el origen de los datos del DataGrid -->
        <Button DataContext="{StaticResource MyGlobalVM}" Command="MyCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myGrid,Path=DataContext}" Content="DoIt" />        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```